# Ruby "instance variable not initialized" warning

Tags: ruby

In writing some "learning the language" code in ruby, as part of a linkedList implementation, I came across this warning:

In the "add" method, the head is created if it doesn't already exist, i.e.

```
  def add(value)
   new_node=LinkedListNode.new(value)
   if !@head
     @head=new_node
   else
     self.find {|node| node.next ==nil }.next=new_node
   end
  end
```

I then get the warning

```
.../linked_list.rb:13: warning: instance variable @head not initialized
```

How do I get rid of this warning? What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: It's a terrible warning is the short answer...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to Matchu's suggestion, you can also use `defined?` to initialize `@head` lazily here without provoking the warning:

```
if defined? @head
  ...
else
  @head = new_node
end
```

The normal idiom for this sort of thing is

```
@head ||= new_node
```

which will also not provoke the warning, but in this case it seems like you need to do something if `@head` wasn't defined, and it's not idempotent so `||=` is not going to work very well in this case. `||=` also has the disadvantage of not being able to distinguish between false, nil or unset. Initializing to `nil` in initialize is probably the best choice.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the fact the warning goes away with ruby 3.0 makes me wonder if it could be disabled in ruby 2.7 instead...

Answer (score 10):

You could declare `@head` as `nil` in the `initialize` method, for one.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in those cases, it's better to use native `attr_accessor` over the `defined?` check, for example:

```
 attr_accessor :head

 def add(value)
   new_node=LinkedListNode.new(value)
   if !head
     self.head=new_node
   else
     self.find {|node| node.next ==nil }.next=new_node
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
def position
  self.find {|node| node.next.nil? }
end

def head
  @head ||= nil
end

def add value
  node = LinkedListNode.new(value)
  head ? position.next = node : @head = node
end
```

Comment: add value will not parse correctly as a method name

everything else is honky dory

Answer (score -4):

You can't perform the `!` operation on `@head` if it doesn't exist. You need to initialize it first. You should probably declare it as `nil`.

Comment: you can perform `!` on an uninitialized instance var, it's just that you'll get a warning ;)